# Rails 3 can not find sqlite3-ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to learn rails3.

I tried folowing the installation guide from guides.rails.info, I installed

`sudo gem install  rake rack-test rack-mount erubis mail`
`sudo gem install tzinfo builder i18n memcache-client`
`sudo gem install text-format thor`

And rails 3 via

`sudo gem install rails --pre`

Now I create a new app

`rails abc`

And try

`rake db:create`

Which fails with

`Could not find gem 'sqlite3-ruby (>= 0, runtime)' in any of the sources.`

So I try installing `sqlite3-ruby`

`sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby`

Which fails with

`Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.`

So I install it via apt-get

`sudo aptitude install libsqlite3-ruby1.8`.

And still get same error on `rake db:create`.

Comment: I get this with rake db:create --trace. dpaste.de/Lf2E

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be caused by a number of things. So I have a number of questions too. ;)

Is this Debian or Ubuntu? I'm going to assume Ubuntu.

I also assume, because you tried installing `libsqlite3-ruby1.8`, that you are also running Ruby 1.8? Do you have any other versions of Ruby installed? And what does `ruby --version` say?

Ubuntu versions it's Ruby packages as `ruby1.8`, `ruby1.9.0`, and `ruby1.9.1`. Look for those in your package manager. The package named just `ruby` is a dummy that depends on whatever is the default version for Ubuntu at that time.

When you start `irb` and do `require 'sqlite3'`, what is the output?

As for the gem install not working, if you want to try that again, do you have the `ruby-dev` and `libsqlite3-dev` Ubuntu packages installed?

Comment: Ubuntu 9.10, and `ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i486-linux]`

Comment: Thanks, installing ruby-dev seems to fix it.

Comment: If I may, it didn't work for me (similar problem). If I start `irb` and do `require 'sqlite3'`, I get `LoadError: no such file to load -- sqlite3`. I made sure to install ruby1.9-dev, libsqlite3-dev, and all their dependencies previously..

Comment: @Shawn `irb` on Ubuntu/Debian is Ruby 1.8 by default. So I suspect you're mixing versions too. Compare the paths in the outputs of `gem environment` and `ruby -r rubygems -e 'puts Gem.path'`. (And if you're using Ruby 1.9, also invoke irb with `irb1.9.1`.)

Answer (score 10):

Having played this lottery the thing I found that has worked for me after many different variations complaining about missing sqlite3 libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev
sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby
```

Comment: using sqlite3-ruby instead of just 'sqlite3' in my Gemfile worked.

Comment: Thanks. I did `sudo gem install sqlite3` in the second line and it worked.